Azure Access Packages- How to get the Resource Roles within an Access Packages in Azure using Powershell
I'm new to entitilment management and I want to make a list of the resource roles within an access package, by using the access package IDs. Is there a way to do that using powershell?
I want to see the AAD groups associated with the access packages
I tried using Get-MgBetaEntitlementManagementAccessPackageResource, but everytime I add an access package Id which I know is valid, I get the error that it's null

I have one access package with resource role having one Azure AD group with Owner role like this:

To get these resource roles using Microsoft Graph PowerShell, you can make use of below sample script:
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "EntitlementManagement.Read.All"

$accessPackageId = "61cx1bxx-bx3c-4dx8-8xx-xxxxxx"
$accessPackage = Get-MgEntitlementManagementAccessPackage -AccessPackageId $accessPackageId -ExpandProperty "resourceRoleScopes(`$expand=role,scope)"

if ($accessPackage) {
    # Iterate through each resource role scope
    foreach ($resourceRoleScope in $accessPackage.ResourceRoleScopes) {
        $role = $resourceRoleScope.Role | Where-Object { $_ -ne $null } | Select-Object -Property Description, DisplayName, Id, OriginId, OriginSystem
        $scope = $resourceRoleScope.Scope | Where-Object { $_ -ne $null } | Select-Object -Property Description, DisplayName, Id, IsRootScope, OriginId, OriginSystem

        $modifiedObject = @{
            Id = $resourceRoleScope.Id
            Role = $role
            Scope = $scope
        }

        $jsonResult = $modifiedObject | ConvertTo-Json
        Write-Host $jsonResult
    }
} else {
    Write-Host "Access package not found."
}

Response:

To get the details of groups associated with the access packages, run below command by replacing $groupId with OriginId from above response:
Get-MgGroup -GroupId $groupId

Response:

Reference:
List resourceRoleScopes - Microsoft Graph

I also had this question and the solution above got me 90% there.
My use case was I wanted to input a group name and see what access packages it was in.
This was the script I used based on the first answer:
$group = "group-name"


$groupinfo = get-azureadgroup -SearchString $group
$accesspackages = Get-MgEntitlementManagementAccessPackage
foreach ($accesspackage in $accesspackages) {
    $accessPackageInfo = Get-MgEntitlementManagementAccessPackage -AccessPackageId $accesspackage.Id -ExpandProperty "resourceRoleScopes(`$expand=role,scope)"
    foreach ($resourceRoleScope in $accessPackageInfo.ResourceRoleScopes.Scope) {
        if ($resourceRoleScope.OriginId -eq $groupinfo.ObjectId) {
            Write-Host "Group `"$group`" is in Access Package: $($accesspackage.DisplayName)"
        }
    }
}

